# IntelliJ warning when pom dependency version is outdated

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Small question regarding IntelliJ and Maven pom.xml please.

In several online tutorials, I saw when the user is using IntelliJ, Maven, and has a dependency which version is outdated, got a nice warning.

For instance, in this piece of pom:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The line `<version>3.0.1</version>` will be highlighted in yellow, the tooltip will say this version is outdated, and even gives the user the option to update to fix and IntelliJ would replace with a newer version.

I think this is super handy!

Unfortunately, my pom, when having an outdated version, has no warning of any kind.

May I ask, how to enable those warning when IntelliJ and Maven highlight the outdated dependency version please?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have "Dependencies" tool window in "View | Tool Windows"?

Comment: Indeed, that is correct, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As y.bedrov mentioned, all credits to him, it is under View -> Tool Windows -> Dependencies